# How do I create a git branch so that files I add to it are not added to master?

Tags: git, git-track

I want to create a git branch that will work independent of the master branch. I want all the code that is present in the master till now, but any further changes in the master should not reflect in the branch and any changes in the branch should not reflect in the master.

I used this command to create branch:

```
git branch test
```

But any file I add in `master`, I can see in `test`. And any new file added in `test`, I can see in `master`. How to avoid this? I did not use any --track option while creating the branch.

Comment: That's not supposed to happen at all. Could you detail a bit more how you're doing your commits and branch switching?

Comment: Are you sure you are changing branch through the git checkout command?

Comment: yes, I am changing the branch with git checkout

Comment: By default I am in the master branch. I created a new branch using the command: git branch test
Then, switch to the new branch using: git checkout test
Add a new file in test branch: git add newfile
Switch to master: git checkout master
then: git status
and I find the newfile I added in test branch in the master 
Why do I see the newfile in test branch in master? I want it to be visible only in test branch

Comment: Do you commit your changes before switching?

Comment: No Mat, I am not doing commit before switching. I just do a git add and then switch

Comment: Then the behavior is expected. Commit if you want to save. Use `git stash` if you don't want to commit yet.

Comment: Changes aren't put into a branch until you `commit` them. You're only making changes in your "working copy" which is a separate entity from any branch that you're committing to

Comment: I was able to commit only to the branch. Thanks Mat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've asked for is exactly what `git branch test` does (a point from which the two histories are no longer shared). There is two levels of confusion here though:

- When you `git add newfile`, you are adding it to the index, but not committing it or updating any branch with it's contents. When you check out a new branch then, as long as there is no conflict, git will not reset those changes from the index. This is a desirable behavior, for example if you are working on another branch and want to take only a subset of the uncommitted changes over to another branch. If you `git commit` the state of the index on your original branch, the index won't retain those changes when you go back to the test branch.
- When you move between trees that have new files added or removed, a `git checkout` will not necessarily remove them from the filesystem (if there is a reset operation). Then you may "see" these files when you switch branches, e.g. in the output of `ls` or `git status` -- but they are "untracked" and git will not try to do anything with them (`git commit -a`, for example, will not add this file to the index before writing a new tree). This is nothing to worry about, but if you're OCD about it, you can delete them (or use `git clean`).

Comment: More detailed than my answer. +1. Note, it is not OCD. It is CDO, ie like OCD but in alphabetical order. **As it should be**. (Sorry, it is Friday, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 29):

I think what you wanted was:

```
git checkout --orphan somebranch
```

this will create a `somebranch` with no history whatsoever, you can add which files you want to that one, and they might differ 100% from your previous branches.

Comment: Not what the *OP* wanted, but what most people finding this question do.

Answer (score 3):

```
git branch test
git add .
git checkout test
git checkout master
```

As long as you don't commit, you will see your working tree and your index (which references what you have added) in both branches `test` and `master`.

```
git checkout test
git commit -m "files for test"
git checkout master
```

Then you won't see in `master` the files you have just committed in `test`.
You new branch `test` will have recording a new commit (with new content), independent from `master`.